# How to select voice acting of another language in VoiceOver in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, widget, voiceover

There is a widget in my iOS app. I'm trying to set up voiceover accessibility for VoiceOver for him. But he speaks, anyway, in another language.

Maybe someone has faced such a problem?

Perhaps this is somehow solved by adding parameters to the plist file.

Swift
Xcode
iOS
Widget